# JSON profile for Room Controls (ZoomRoom)

Tags: json, zoom-sdk

I need to integrate a Sony TV and send commands to a control system but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to format the commands.
Sony KD65X80K IP:10.4.201.228 Port:20060 [https://pro-bravia.sony.net/develop/integrate/ssip/command-definitions/index.html](https://drivercentral.io/platforms/control4-drivers/utility/generic-tcp-command-control4-driver-chowmain/)
Control 4 IP: 10.4.201.195:49412
Commands http://10.4.201.195:49412/tvOneOn, http://10.4.201.195:49412/tvOneOff

**Edit**
Sony TV IP:10.4.201.228,
Control4 IP:10.4.201.195:49412.
I need to make a Json file for native room controls (zoomRoom).
I need to control The Sony Bravia TV and Control4 (automation) system.
How do I add this device to the Json file?
Sony Bravia Commands:
Power On,
Power Off,
Input 1,
Input 2,

Control4 commands:
I am using the TCP driver from drivercentral.io
[Generic TCP Command](https://drivercentral.io/platforms/control4-drivers/utility/generic-tcp-command-control4-driver-chowmain/)
It uses http commands like "http://10.4.201.195:49412/tvOneOn"

How would I write said commands?
Zoom Documentation
[Zoom Rooms Native Room Controls](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360033716572)

**Edit**
I edited the Json to use the Sony Bravia Simple IP commands. I cannot find any example of HTTP Get requests working in zoom.
For Sony Bravia you have to start the code with a *S and finish it with a \n
For example, power on would be *SCPOWR0000000000000001\n

I also found a Zoom JSON configuration file maker. https://controlconcepts.net/zoom

Does anyone know if I can do HTTP GET requests?

//JSON

```html
{
  "about": {
    "app": "CCI Zoom Room Profile Maker",
    "version": "v0.2.5",
    "url": "https://controlconcepts.net/zoom/",
    "created": "Mon, 22 Aug 2022 17:57:25 GMT"
  },
  "adapters": [
    {
      "model": "GenericNetworkAdapter",
      "ip": "tcp://10.4.201.228:20060",
      "ports": [
        {
          "id": "tvLeft",
          "name": "TV Left",
          "methods": [
            {
              "id": "power",
              "name": "Power",
              "command": "*SCPOWR000000000000000%\n",
              "params": [
                {
                  "id": "on",
                  "name": "On",
                  "value": "1"
                },
                {
                  "id": "off",
                  "name": "Off",
                  "value": "0"
                }
              ],
              "type": "actions"
            },
            {
              "id": "input",
              "name": "Input",
              "command": "*SCINPT000000010000000%\n",
              "params": [
                {
                  "id": "input1",
                  "name": "Input 1",
                  "value": "1"
                },
                {
                  "id": "input2",
                  "name": "Input 2",
                  "value": "2"
                }
              ],
              "type": "actions"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "styles": [],
  "rules": {
    "meeting_started": [],
    "meeting_ended": [],
    "microphone_muted": [],
    "microphone_unmuted": [],
    "video_started": [],
    "video_stopped": [],
    "operation_time_started": [],
    "operation_time_ended": []
  }
}
```

//end of JSON

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In Native Room Controls (ZoomRoom) I have to make a Json file that sends commands to a Sony Bravia TV using simple-ip-control. I also have to send http commands to a control system. I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

Comment: I could also use Sony's API but don't know how I would format this.

Comment: The example above is trying to execute a http command to the control system which has the TV integrated.
I have 2 options. Direct control or thought the control system with http commands.
either way I have to make both methods work because the control system controls the lighting.

Comment: Why do you edit the question. Update and format it with all the relevant information  and [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and share the code of what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I edited the best I could just now considering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I edited the Json to use the Sony Bravia Simple IP commands. I cannot
> find any example of HTTP Get requests working in zoom. For Sony Bravia
> you have to start the code with a *S and finish it with a \n For
> example, power on would be *SCPOWR0000000000000001\n
>
> I also found a Zoom JSON configuration file maker.
> https://controlconcepts.net/zoom
>
> Does anyone know if I can do HTTP GET requests?

```html
{
  "about": {
    "app": "CCI Zoom Room Profile Maker",
    "version": "v0.2.5",
    "url": "https://controlconcepts.net/zoom/",
    "created": "Mon, 22 Aug 2022 17:57:25 GMT"
  },
  "adapters": [
    {
      "model": "GenericNetworkAdapter",
      "ip": "tcp://10.4.201.228:20060",
      "ports": [
        {
          "id": "tvLeft",
          "name": "TV Left",
          "methods": [
            {
              "id": "power",
              "name": "Power",
              "command": "*SCPOWR000000000000000%\n",
              "params": [
                {
                  "id": "on",
                  "name": "On",
                  "value": "1"
                },
                {
                  "id": "off",
                  "name": "Off",
                  "value": "0"
                }
              ],
              "type": "actions"
            },
            {
              "id": "input",
              "name": "Input",
              "command": "*SCINPT000000010000000%\n",
              "params": [
                {
                  "id": "input1",
                  "name": "Input 1",
                  "value": "1"
                },
                {
                  "id": "input2",
                  "name": "Input 2",
                  "value": "2"
                }
              ],
              "type": "actions"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "styles": [],
  "rules": {
    "meeting_started": [],
    "meeting_ended": [],
    "microphone_muted": [],
    "microphone_unmuted": [],
    "video_started": [],
    "video_stopped": [],
    "operation_time_started": [],
    "operation_time_ended": []
  }
}
```